# Sparse.model.matrix error message

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dummy-variable

I'm trying to create a sparse-matrix and get this error message:

> Error: fnames == names(mf) are not all TRUE

I think it has something to do with the column names of my data, maybe you can help.

Here are the column names:

> Error: fnames == names(mf) are not all TRUE

```
colnames(trainDataShrinkage) <-"Bildungsgrad2_Lower_secondary_education"                   
 ,"Bildungsgrad3_Upper_secondary_education"                    
 ,"Bildungsgrad4_Post-secondary_non-tertiary_education"        
 ,"Bildungsgrad5_Short-cycle_tertiary_education"               
 ,"Bildungsgrad6_Bachelors_or_equivalent_level"                
 ,"Bildungsgrad7_Masters_or_equivalent_level"                  
 ,"Bildungsgrad8_Doctoral_or_equivalent_level"                 
 ,"Familienstand2_Verheiratet,_getrenntlebend"                 
 ,"Familienstand3_Ledig"                                       
 ,"Familienstand4_Geschieden,_eing._gleichg._Partn._aufgehoben"
 ,"Familienstand5_Verwitwet,_Lebenspartner/in_verstorben"      
 ,"Familienstand6_Eing._gleichg._Partn.,_zusammenlebend"       
 ,"Geschlecht2_Weiblich"                                       
 ,"Migrationshintergrund2_direkter_Migrationshintergrund"      
 ,"Migrationshintergrund3_indirekter_Migrationshintergrund"    
 ,"Bundesland2_Hamburg"                                        
 ,"Bundesland3_Niedersachsen"                                  
 ,"Bundesland4_Bremen"                                         
 ,"Bundesland5_Nordrhein-Westfalen"                            
 ,"Bundesland6_Hessen"                                         
 ,"Bundesland7_Rheinland-Pfalz"                                
 ,"Bundesland8_Baden-Wuerttemberg"                             
 ,"Bundesland9_Bayern"                                         
 ,"Bundesland10_Saarland"                                      
 ,"Bundesland11_Berlin_(West_und_Ost)"                         
 ,"Bundesland12_Brandenburg"                                   
 ,"Bundesland13_Mecklenburg-Vorpommern"                        
 ,"Bundesland14_Sachsen"                                       
 ,"Bundesland15_Sachsen-Anhalt"                                
 ,"Bundesland16_Thueringen"                                    
 ,"Unternehmengroesse2_5 bis_10"                               
 ,"Unternehmengroesse3_11_bis_unter_20"                        
 ,"Unternehmengroesse6_20_bis_unter_100"                       
 ,"Unternehmengroesse7_100_bis_unter_200"                      
 ,"Unternehmengroesse9_200_bis_unter_2000"                     
 ,"Unternehmengroesse10_2000_und_mehr"                         
 ,"Erwerbsstatus2_Teilzeitbeschaeftigung"                      
 ,"Erwerbsstatus4_Geringfuegig_beschaeftigt"                   
 ,"Stundenlohn"                                                  
 ,"AlterEins"                                                    
 ,"AlterZwei"                                                    
 ,"AlterDrei"                                                    
 ,"AlterFuenF"                                                   
 ,"AlterSechs"                                                   
 ,"BildungsjahreEins"                                            
 ,"BildungsjahreZwei"                                            
 ,"BildungsjahreDrei"                                            
 ,"BildungsjahreVier"                                            
 ,"BildungsjahreFuenf"                                           
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeitEins"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeitZwei"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeitDrei"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeitVier"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeitFuenf"                           
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeitEins"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeitZwei"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeitDrei"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeitVier"                            
 ,"ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeitFuenf"                           
 ,"BruttoverdienstLetztenMonatEins"                              
 ,"BruttoverdienstLetztenMonatZwei"                              
 ,"BruttoverdienstLetztenMonatDrei"                              
 ,"BruttoverdienstLetztenMonatVier"                              
 ,"BruttoverdienstLetztenMonatFuenf")
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not like some special characters in the column names. I faced issues with column names starting with #, 1, . and /. Can you try to replace these occurrences with '_'.

Simplest way would be to trim your column names off any special characters. Let me know if you cannot rename them due to any limitation.

Comment: i replaced all ,    .  /  -    with _ and still have they same error

Comment: Did you also replace '()' ?

Comment: okay i found the reason why it didnt worked. I also have to replace spaces with _

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot to mention Spaces. Its that and any special characters. Glad it worked out. Happy Coding!

Comment: I've solved a similar error converting the matrix into a data.frame.